# In which territories is there no income tax for its residents?

Tags: taxes, income-tax

In which territories (countries, potentially sub-country entities) is there no personal income tax from any administration (neither federal, state, local, nor any other level) levied on the income of permanent residents of that territory?

One example is [Monaco](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monaco). Are there any others? Can we try to make a complete list?

---

**Notes:**

- I am not interested in examples like some U.S.-states with no state income tax, but where federal income tax still applies - I declare such and similar answers as off-topic.
- I also exclude territories with no permanent residents - such as oceans, the Arctic, the Moon, the [ISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Space_Station), etc. Only territories that do have permanent human residents and are on the land surface of planet Earth count.

Comment: What about remote islands with native people still living in barter world. Do these count? :)

Comment: @Dheer if the jurisdiction under which the island lies, does not levy income tax on its residents, then of course it counts.

Comment: So would something like Sealand make to your list? Kidding ;) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principality_of_Sealand

Comment: @Dheer I assume it would, but if it does I think it makes the question a lot less interesting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Monaco is a very unique and extraordinary country. It compensates on the lack of personal income tax with [a very hefty corporation tax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tax_rates_around_the_world) from the employers (many employees in Monaco are actually French residents, and Monaco residents who are French citizens pay French taxes).

There aren't many places like Monaco.

[Andorra](http://www.lowtax.net/lowtax/html/janpetx.html), another European city-state, is one of the few.

Another example is [UAE](http://www.infoprod.co.il/country/uae2e.htm), they have enough oil for all their needs.

[Wikipedia - Tax rates around the world](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tax_rates_around_the_world) covers all you need.

Note that being resident of a country with no income tax is not enough. <strike>*Many*</strike>There are countries (US included) that tax their citizens on the world-wide income. Thus, US citizens living as residents in Monaco still have to pay the US income taxes.

Comment: "many countries"? actually is there any other country besides the US which taxes its citizens on world-wide income?

Comment: @miernik Most 1st world countries do. Canada is another example.

Comment: @Saideira source? [here](http://renunciationguide.com/Citizenship-Based-Taxation-International-Comparison.html) it says: lifelong taxation regardless of residency is extremely rare. In 1995, the U.S. Congress took (yet another) look at the situation and found that only 3 countries in the world taxed based on citizenship rather than residency: Phillipines, Eritrea, and the United States. A year later, the Phillipines ended its citizenship-based tax regime. So are you saying that only US, Eritrea and one more country are "1st world countries"? So which is the third 1-st world country?

Comment: "Canada is another example". Do you have a reference for that? I find that "As a non-resident of Canada, you pay tax on **income you receive from sources in Canada**" only. http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/tx/nnrsdnts/ndvdls/nnrs-eng.html

Comment: Also the UK does not tax its citizens on income not earned in the UK if they are non-resident.

Comment: @DJClayworth The original question is about **permanent residents**, so in that context, then yes Canada taxes world income.  Your quote on the other hand was referring to *non-residents*.

Comment: Canada and the UK (unlike the US) do not tax their citizens who are legally resident overseas and have no Canadian income. Your answer appears to imply differently. Maybe you should clarify what you mean.

Comment: @miernik, yes, there are several other countries like that, definitely. Actually, many more countries move towards world-wide taxation as a result of the glottalization.

Comment: @DJClayworth - where did I mention Canada in my answer?

Comment: UK and Canada are examples demonstrating that "Many countries" (other than the US) don't tax non-residents on foreign income. "Moving towards" is not the same as "do".

Comment: @DJClayworth - did I say "all"? I know that US does, Israel does, and these are countries I pay taxes at. Canada? Don't know and don't care.

Comment: @miernik - residency in one country doesn't necessarily mean non-residency in another. I've been, myself, resident in two different countries at the same time (paying taxes in both). Each country has its own tests for residency, and physical presence being only one of the criteria.

Comment: I wonder if I were to renounce my US citizenship and declare for Monaco if Washington would get its hand out of my ....

Comment: @Chad - Monaco can't wait for you to move in.

Comment: @littleadv and the poster here, the US taxing citizens around the world sounds like a lot, but you can't forget about the IRS' foreign earned income exclusion (if you work for wages), where over $90,000 of yearly income is tax free to the US, you still have to pay local authorities and be mindful of tax treaties, but if you are a resident of a jurisdiction with no income tax, then $90,000 to the bank! of course this is too low to live in Monaco, but the UAE or Cayman Islands is a good bet. You don't have to consider renouncing US citizenship for this

Comment: @littleadv: source that Israel has income tax on its citizens living permanently abroad? AFAIK the only countries that has income tax on its citizens living permanently abroad is United States and Eritrea, and contrary to what you write there are no countries "moving towards" that. In fact the opposite: Philippines abolished such tax.

Comment: @miernik well, apparently you know wrong. But if you can prove you're right to the Israeli Tax Authority, I personally will thank you. As will all the rest of the Israelis abroad. BTW: we're not discussing people who live permanently somewhere else, look again at your question. Nothing "permanent" there. In Israel, you have to prove that you have no intentions of returning to Israel, in addition to currently not being resident, which is obviously a very difficult thing to prove (especially if most people actually do want to come back at some point).

Comment: @littleadv that's just details on how Israel defines a resident. If their definition of resident includes someone who doesn't currently physically live in Israel, but only intends to return to Israel, then its just that he is still "mentally" resident in Israel. But someone who doesn't intend to return to Israel, will not have to pay Israeli income tax, yes? But he can remain a Israeli citizen (keep his passport), yes? If so, then I am right - Israeli non-resident citizens don't pay Israeli income tax.

Comment: @miernik, the point is that the definition of who is resident for taxes in Israel is not clearly defined, and it can be argued that every Israeli citizen is by definition a resident until the citizenship is renounced. Israeli law allows that. That makes the question of residency irrelevant.

Comment: @miernik - regardless, this lengthy and fruitless discussion has nothing to do with your original question. I suggest you accept my answer as it answers the question asked. If you have any more questions - just open another question, don't keep posting here arguing about stuff not relevant to the topic.